# What is the equivalent GPA for Cum Laude in Spain?

Tags: phd, mathematics, gpa, spain

I defended my thesis in Spain with *cum laude*. My PhD program was research based. Now I am in the employment process and I have been asked to provide equivalence to *cum laude*. Could you please help me to obtain this information?

Comment: In the US, *cum laude* is used for undergraduate degrees; rarely or never for Ph.D.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is that cum laude was awarded for the thesis, not for GPA. In some other places (US, for example), cum laude is often awarded for some varying but specific GPA, like 3.5/4.0. I'll guess the one asking for information has that in mind.

Just explain what it is, how it was awarded, and that it wasn't GPA related.

The world is a big place. It isn't especially uniform. It would be a bit boring if it were. (And, congratulations)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there exists an online formula that I  need to fill up and it does not accept explanation. But I will try to explain to them

Comment: Can you fill in N. A. (not applicable) or the equivalent? Or "0.0" would get their attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but in my experience Cum Laude is virtually meaningless in Spain. At least at the institute where I obtained my PhD, almost everyone graduates Cum Laude.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say cum laude could be translated by 'With Honors' and you can just have this Cum Laude distinction when you have a 10/10 grade.

With honors enables you to qualify for the extraordinary award for your thesis. Ther is a max% of extraordinary awards granted per university and it also depends on the impact your thesis generates (in terms of articles... etc)

Comment: You might now the graduations in Spain. In Germany, there is summa cum laude, magna cum laude, cum laude, and rite.